# How to get rid of snap

Tags: firefox, snap, netbeans

I have an application that uses QDesktopServices to open a tab in the default browser (Firefox) but when I start my app, it starts Netbeans instead of Firefox. Snap seems to be the reason so I want to get rid of it.

Comment: You've not provided your OS/release details, but why get rid of snap, with what you describe as a problem related to `xdg-open` ?? Your short description is without sufficient detail & jumps to a conclusion your detail doesn't directly link.  Have you considered the consequences (*mainly in the future*) for you *unstated* OS & system? considered the additional maintenance burden included in your *unclear* (you gave no OS details) wanted direction?